# How to find the new median

Tags: statistics

The median score of a 19 student was 58, A 20th  student who had a score of 45 joined the group. What is the new median score ?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: recall the median is the middle-most number. If you add another term to the left half of the median, what happens? Make sure you know the difference between the median and mean... are you sure you're asking about median?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.